# How do I delay a jQuery animation after a page loads?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Here's my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UuD8s/5/

```
$("#transition")
    .delay(5000)
    .animate({ width: "400px" }, { duration: 1000, queue: true });

$("#transition")
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({ left: "100px" }, { duration: 1000, queue: true });​
```

I want to delay my second animation start after the page launches with a 2 second delay.
The problem is it starts after the first animation. If `queue` is set to `false` there is no delay at all.

How would I delay the animation 2 seconds after page launch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to delay your animation after page launch set `queue` to false and use a `setTimeout` of two seconds:

```
$("#transition")
    .delay(5000)
    .animate({width: "400px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true});

setTimeout(function() {

    $("#transition").delay(2000).animate({ left: "100px" }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
    });

}, 2000);​
```

Here's a [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UuD8s/6/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method to delay javascript functions.

```
$("#transition").delay(5000).animate({width: "400px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: true});
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#transition").delay(2000).animate({left: "100px"}, {duration: 1000, queue: false});  
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want the second animation (the left one) to start 2 seconds after launch. This will take 1 second. You want the first one to start 5 seconds after launch.

So what you can do is queue them up so that two seconds after the left one finishes the width one kicks in...

```
$("#transition").delay(2000).animate({left: "100px"}, {duration: 1000});
$("#transition").delay(2000).animate({width: "400px"}, {duration: 1000});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UuD8s/7/

This does solve it for the situation you have above where they are not running simultaneously but if you do want them to run simultaneouly (eg the width should start shrinking half way through the movement) then this will not work.